# Mysql - order by 2 ranks

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table of items. item has id, score 1, score 2.

I want to select 12 known items (using `WHERE id IN (....)`) and order them by a score that is the sum of score1 and score2's **ranks**. rank is the location of the score if the 12 items were ordered by it.

How can I do this in mysql?

**Edit:**

After 4 answers I see that the solution is probably more complicated than I expected. so let me ask the question in another way.

If I use `select *, [calculation] from table where id IN (odered list of ids)`. Can I somehow use the position of each id in the original ordered list of ids in `[calculation]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of my head:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_1(score_1_rank INT AUTO_INCREMENT, id)
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_2(score_2_rank INT AUTO_INCREMENT, id)

INSERT INTO t_1(id)
SELECT id
FROM items i
WHERE id IN () 
ORDER BY score_1

INSERT INTO t_2(id)
SELECT id
FROM items i
WHERE id IN ()
ORDER BY score_2

SELECT ...
FROM   items i
INNER JOIN t_1 t1
  ON t1.id = i.id
INNER JOIN t_2 t2
  ON t2.id = i.id
ORDER BY t1.rank + t2.rank
```

Did I understand your request correctly?

Comment: Thanks! It definately does what I want but I need the most efficient way to do that.

Comment: For MySQL, I dont know how to do it in one query as Im more used to MSSQL. 
You could put this in a stored procedure or possibly create views instead of the first two inserts.
If you are looking for efficiency, then reconsider using the IN() clause too...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking to do?

```
SELECT
(CAST(score1 AS INT) + CAST(score2 AS INT)) AS rank
FROM items
WHERE id IN(...)
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

Comment: No. I need the sum of the ranks of the scores (their location when sorted from largest to smallest), not the scores themselves.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, score1, score2, 
    r1.rank AS rank1, 
    r2.rank AS rank2, 
    (r1.rank + r2.rank) rankSum
FROM items i
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, id
    FROM items, (SELECT @rank :=0) AS r
    ORDER BY score1
) AS r1 ON r1.id = i.id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, id
    FROM items, (SELECT @rank :=0) AS r
    ORDER BY score2
) AS r2 ON r2.id = i.id
ORDER BY rankSum
```

But I doubt that this will be somehow very efficient, not only because the query cannot make use of the query cache.